# Django Tweepy Streaming in browser

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I want to implement a live streamer in the browser of the Tweeter data.
I am using Tweepy library to stream the tweets.

```
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        return status.text
```

This allows me to stream the data to the console, however, I would like to stream and display the data in the browser. What are the steps to achieve that? Should I use Ajax to make a request from time to time in order to populate the data? Is it possible to achieve this by using only the Tweepy library?

Comment: Not sure exactly, but I'd look into channels.